# SQL: how to get the position for split part

Tags: sql, regex, string, postgresql

Let's say I have a url 'www.dummy.url.com'
I want to first try to use non-regex functions such as split_part to get the last 2 of the split strings 'url' and 'com' in this case.

If I knew what the positions were, then I could get it, but let's say the url's can be in the form of url.com, www.url.com, or asdf.asdf.asdf.url.com.
In that case I don't know what to put for the parameter for
split_part(a random url, '.', ???).

If it isn't possible to do this without regex, could you suggest me a way to do it using regex?

Comment: Please re-explain what you are trying to accomplish without providing a possible solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in PostgreSQL using regex. Just wrote some quick SQL with CTE so you can break them apart and understand at your leisure.

```
with dataset as (
    select regexp_split_to_table('www.dummy.url.com', '\\.') as urlsplit
), 
dataset_withsr as (
    select row_number() over() as sr, urlsplit from dataset
)
select urlsplit from dataset_withsr order by sr desc limit 2

-- Result:
com
url
```

If you wanted to comma separate them like `url, com` then do

```
with dataset as (
    select regexp_split_to_table('www.dummy.url.com', '\\.') as urlsplit
), 
dataset_withsr as (
    select row_number() over() as sr, urlsplit from dataset
), 
required_data as (
    select 1 as col1, sr, urlsplit from dataset_withsr order by sr desc limit 2
),
nicely_ordered_data as (
    select col1, urlsplit from required_data order by sr
)
select col1, string_agg(urlsplit, ', ') from nicely_ordered_data group by col1

-- Result
url, com
```